# How do I return the result of a Firestore query in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble with a Typescript class method (Angular) where I'm trying to return the result from a Firestore query (always going to be a single number), so I'm able to get it from another method and add to Firestore. I should say I'm fairly new to Typescript, Firestore querying and Promises. I haven't found other questions specifically about *returning* from *Firestore query* in *Typescript*.

I understand my return statement is executed before the data is retrieved, but how can I go about returning the result so I can access it in another method and add to Firestore again? I get an error when calling the method in method `startSessionPhase1` as I want to retrieve a number, but the method `getLastSession` is returning a promise.

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'number'.

My class:

```
export class FirebaseService {
  moduleCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Module> = null;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
     this.moduleCollection = afs.collection('Modules');
  }

  getLastSessionP1() {
    var query = this.afs.collection("SessionsPhase1").ref.orderBy('session', "desc").limit(1);
    return query.get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        doc.data().session;
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  }

startSessionPhase1(value) {
    var lastSessionP1: number = this.getLastSessionP1();
    console.log('lastSessionP1: ',lastSessionP1);
    return this.afs.collection('SessionsPhase1').add({
      variable: var, //etc
      session: lastSessionP1,
    });
  })();
}
```

Comment: can you post the whole class ?

Comment: Also what are you getting back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this code

```
 getLastSessionP1(): Promise<number|null> {
    var query = this.afs.collection("SessionsPhase1").ref.orderBy('session', "desc").limit(1);
    return query.get()
      .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.size > 0? querySnapshot.docs[0].data().session: null);
  }

 // method #1
this.getLastSessionP1().then(session => console.log(session));

// method #2
(async function () {    
var lastSessionP1: number = await this.getLastSessionP1();
console.log(lastSessionP1);
})();
```

Comment: I get "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'"

Comment: I should have added that I call the method from another (non-asynchronous) method. I now get the error "'await' expression is only allowed within an async function".

Comment: Great, thanks! I used method 1 and now can declare my `lastSessionP1` variable in the second method. Although, I realised that I get the same problem in this method as I did in the first, that the rest of the method is executed before `lastSessionP1` is set. The return statement in this method adds data to Firestore (including the variable in question). Sorry, I realise, I should update my question with more code! Can I solve this by making method asyncronous and using await?

Comment: No, `getLastSessionP1` already is asynchronous. And you can not  to do it synchronous. It is not depend from  you.

Comment: I meant the second method, where I call `getLastSessionP1()`. But I also realised I get a compiling error when trying to make it asynchronous. Using Angular/Firebase if that has something to do with it?